# How do I assign a variable to a selected ID value for use in repeat Selects (fetches)?

Tags: php, variables, select, forum

I am developing a travel rideshare/rideboard, with minimal-info posts arranged on a page according to user inputs. The minimals protects the user's info, until someone clicks on VIEW ENTIRE POST, which exposes all (cautioned, at-their-own-risk!) trip data on a separate page.

Here is the minimal-post code:`

```
`the fetch`
   $sql = "SELECT ID, alias, grouporg, choosefrom, chooseto, going, arriving, gender 
    FROM drivers ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
        $selres = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $selrescheck = mysqli_num_rows($selres);
```

Code excerpt - outputting to the minimal posts:

```
<?php 
if ($selrescheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selres)) {
        ?>
        <fieldset><span style="color: #204d74;">
        <legend>post id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?></legend>
        <label>POSTED by:   <?php echo $row['alias']; ?></label>
        <label>~~ I am organizing <?php echo $row['grouporg']; ?> Travel</label>
         ~~I am a:   <?php echo $row['gender']; ?></label>
         <label>From:    <?php echo $row['choosefrom']; ?>~~</label>
        <label> To:    <?php echo $row['chooseto']; ?></label>
        <label>planned LEAVE:   <?php echo $row['going']; ?>~~</label>
        <label>planned ARRIVAL:   <?php echo $row['arriving']; ?> </label></span>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <h2 align="left"><a href="../next page.php">
         <span style="color:#F51EED;">**View Entire Post**</span></a></h2>
        </fieldset>
    }
}
```

The posts turn out nicely, and let's say that 'ID' = 71 in this example. When an interested user wants to see more info, they will see the full row data via this SELECT (so far):

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE ID='$ID'";  
    $selres = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $selrescheck = mysqli_num_rows($selres);
```

Whereas `$ID (or some variable) = 71` in this post, but how do I capture that unique ID value in each post, ***that will carry over to the next page***? (Obviously I can't pencil in the actual number every time!)

Appreciating your time so much.

Comment: I've improved the overall formatting of your post and removed some redundant remarks.

Comment: yes, appreciated! my FIRST post to the Stack......i've been following the work here for eons, never jumped in. i do need to polish up my act a bit

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to use something like this `<h2 align="left"><a href="../next page.php?ID=<?= $row['ID']; ?>"> <span style="color:#F51EED;">**View Entire Post**</span></a></h2>`. Then you can access the ID through $_REQUEST['ID]

Comment: I don't know if i understand your question but you can use the select by id query like this: $sql = "SELECT * FROM drivers WHERE ID={$_REQUEST['ID]}";

Comment: i guess my comments got wiped, as i wrote what worked, following on @Duarte answer. what's important is it was SUCCESS, and very appreciated! cheers im